# Cannot assign an if statement to a variable

Tags: raku

The problem here is that I do not understand well the difference between statements and blocks in control flow.

Looking the ternary operator I can use it to assign a variable. But this is an operator, so it is like applying a function--isn't it?

```
> my $variable = True ?? 34 !! 42;
34
```

since in the raku documentation says:

[`if` documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#if)

> `if`
>
> To conditionally run a block of code, use an `if` followed by a
> condition. The condition, an expression, will be evaluated immediately
> after the statement before the `if` finishes. The block attached to the
> condition will only be evaluated if the condition means `True` when
> coerced to Bool. Unlike some languages the condition does not have to
> be parenthesized, instead the `{` and `}` around the block are mandatory:

[`do` documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#do)

> `do`
>
> The simplest way to run a block where it cannot be a stand-alone statement is by writing `do` before it:

so this should work in both cases:

```
> my $variable = do {34};
34

> my $variable = if True {34;} else {43;} 
===SORRY!===
Word 'if' interpreted as a listop; please use 'do if' to introduce the statement control word
------> my $variable = if⏏ True {34;} else {43;} 
Unexpected block in infix position (two terms in a row)
------> my $variable = if True⏏ {34;} else {43;}
```

as said in the error I need to add the `do`:

```
> my $variable = do if True {34;} else {43;} 
34
```

So the `if` really does not run the block...or what is the real problem here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: The actual difference is between *statement* and *expression*, not *statement* and *block*. `do` is a statement prefix that creates expressions.

---

`if` actually creates a statement (anything that is run in Raku is), however, what it's not is an [expression](https://docs.raku.org/language/syntax#Statements_and_expressions). `do` is a statement prefix, and what it does is turn statements into expressions.

However, `if` is not really a first-class function that you can assign to a variable or handle around. Whenever you find pieces of syntax such as that one (or `for`, for instance), you need to prefix them with `do` to "expressionify" them.

```
say &say.^name;# OUTPUT: «Sub␤»                                                                                                 say &do.^name; # OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Undeclared  routine:␤...
say &if.^name; # OUTPUT: «===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <tmp>␤Undeclared routine:␤    if used at line 1␤␤»
```

So `if`, by itself, does not create a block, it does not create an expression, it simply creates a statement. You need to precede it with `do` if you want it to actually turn it into a expression. It does *run* the block that's behind it, however.

Let's go back to the original question, statements and blocks. [Blocks](https://docs.raku.org/type/Block) are objects, first-class citizens. You can use them, apply them, pass them around.

```
my &ifs = { if $_ {34} else {43}};
ifs(True).say; # OUTPUT: «34␤»
```

Statements are throwaway blocks you simply run. In some cases, they are also expressions: they yield a result which, then, you can assign.

```
my &ifs = { if $_ {34} else {43}};
my $result = ifs(True).say; # OUTPUT: «34␤»
say $result;                # OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

The `ifs(True).say` statement prints to output, it also produces a result that can be assigned. All three lines are also statements, and as a matter of fact, expressions too.

Some control structures, however, do not create expressions.

> Some others do; `for` creates a expression; `while` does not.

`if` is an example of this. They don't produce a result. You use them for the side effects: running a statement (if true) or another (if not). You might turn them into a block, as above, and pass them around. Or you can just precede them with `do` and make them produce a throwaway result, which you can then use.

So it will very much depend on your actual use case. You can surround the if statement with curly braces and create a block; or you can simply use the result creating an expression. Or you might want to use it just for the side effects, doing nothing.